Python PyPDF Displaying "If this message is not eventually.." etc. message when attempting to read multiple PDFs
I'm hoping to get some assistance. I'm trying to pull data from several PDFs and output a csv file. When I run the Python script, it will pull data correctly from the first PDF it ingests, but further PDFs after that give this message: "If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document." etc. As I understand it based on my troubleshooting, that is the actual PDF document, and the other stuff is XML that isn't being loaded.
Here's the method that is reading the PDFs with the PdfReader:
def parse_pdf(file_list):
    i = 0
    user_dict = {}
    while i < len(file_list):
        filename = os.path.join(INTAKE_FILEPATH, file_list[i])
        reader = PdfReader(filename)
        page = reader.pages[0]
        fields = reader.get_fields()
        text = page.extract_text()
        name_l = get_name_l(text)
        serial_num = get_serial_num_s(text)
        signed_l = check_if_signed_l(name_l, fields)
        loc_l = get_loc_deros_l(text)
        contact_l = get_contact_info_l(text)
        user_list[i] = assemble_dict(name_l, signed_l, loc_l, contact_l, serial_num)
        ##ISSUES WITH READING MULTIPLE TIMES
        i += 1
    return user_list

The first PDF read in outputs exactly what I'm looking for, but any subsequent PDFs have the message at the top when read in by the PdfReader. Any help is appreciated, thank you.
I attempted to use other libraries, but several are having trouble reading the PDF, I have tried changing the loop around a bit in hopes that maybe in needed to get out of the parse_pdf method and go back, I tried using sleep and giving it 5 minutes, and I'm not sure what else I can try.
UPDATE: It appears it can read multiple signed files just fine, but if the file is unsigned (there is place for a signature within the document) it cannot read the output and instead displays the "If this message is not eventually.."etc.
I believe this is because when the document is not signed, it is a form but when once it has been signed it seems to lose the fields.

Please give us a [mre] so we can provide better answers to your question. First, experiment a little to figure out the simplest program that produces this error - that'll help narrow down the issue. Then, give us enough code that we can test it right out of the box, as well as some example data.

To prove the issue is with "READING MULTIPLE TIMES" can you skip the first PDF and see if it works fine with the second one in the list?

Shouldn't you close the previous file end of the loop every time?

add reader.close() last line of your loop

I tried adding reader.close() and was still getting the same issue. It seems it can read multiple PDFs as long as they are not forms. When the PDF is a form (before the user signs) the text that pypdf gets from it is the "If this message is not.. " ..etc. I'm checking if other methods can parse data from the PDF when it is in this state.
